# How to put a dot in a function (ex.: lib.genarate() )

Tags: javascript

How can I call a function with a dot? For example:
`lib.execute();` or `hello.greet();`

Of course this doesn't work:

```js
function hello.world() {
  document.write('Hello world');
}
```

```html
<button onclick="hello.world();">Click me</button>
```

I have seen somewhere that it used variables, but I do not remember how to use it

Comment: `lib.execute` is not a "function". `lib` is an object that has a method with the name `execute`

Comment: Why do you *want* to have a dot character in a function name (or variable name, or any name)?  Given all of the problems that can *cause*, what is the problem you're trying to *solve*?

Comment: [Working with objects - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Comment: You might want to read up on [Object-oriented programming](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object-oriented_JS), where you can then call a method on an instance of an object using the dot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way of doing as you wish in your example would be something like:

```
let go = {
    abc: function() {
        document.write('Hello world!');
    }
}
```

You need to create a class, or an object that act as a class, and then you can create properties as functions on it.

Comment: Don't confuse objects with classes.

Comment: As I said in my answer, this can be one with either an Object that "act as a class" or creating a class itself. My method was creating a simple object that act as a class to use as OP wished.

Comment: The object **does not** act as a class. If you tried to do `const myInstance = new go()` it would throw an exception.

Comment: I meant syntax wise. Sorry for the misleading spelling.